# Where do I find the source for a namespace in an android activity.xml file

Tags: android, android-layout, xml-namespaces

I see the following in my `activity.xml`:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            app:fabSize="normal"
            app:elevation="20dp"
            app:layout_gravity="end"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="6dp"

            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:src="@drawable/xyz"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            />
```

My compiler complains as follows:

```
Error:(26) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_gravity' in package 'com.android.app'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`app:layout_gravity="end"` needs to be `android:layout_gravity="end"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if a full list of Android XML Namespaces exists,
but in this case the `layout_gravity` attribute is part of the `android:` namespace, not of the `app:` namespace.

If you add the android namespace:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

You can then use `android:layout_gravity` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Change `app:layout_gravity="end"` to `android:layout_gravity="end"`

or if you want to add anchor gravity then use this:

```
app:layout_anchorGravity="end"
```